# How can I use Nagios to act as a SNMP manager?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, nagios, network-monitoring

I have a Nagios Core 3.x setup and A linux-based appliance that has the capability to send SNMP alerts to a server. 
How can I use my Nagios to leverage its snmp monitoring capabilities ???

Answer (score 2):

You should read their documentation [here](http://www.nagios.com/solutions/snmp-traps/)

> Nagios provides management of SNMP traps - including the ability to
>   read, process, and generate alerts from SNMP traps it receives. Nagios
>   can also send SNMP traps to other management hosts, which allows
>   seamless integration with other Network Management Systems.

I've used SNMPtt with Nagios with great success. You can install it with Nagios using these instructions: http://www.snmptt.org/docs/snmptt.shtml#Nagios-Netsaint